# phpdismod / phpenmod -s parameter

Tags: php, command-line-interface, fpm

I would like to know the difference when using `phpdismod`/`phpenmod` with and without the `-s` parameter.

Wasn't able to find a documentation or man-page about this command(s).

I've already understood that I can differ between php-versions and SAPIs, also understood that it also works without the `-s` parameter.

But I don't think everyone would suggest the `-s` parameter just for fun.

Comment: Use the -s flag to define a specific SAPI if you don't want all of them affected.

Comment: SAPI - cli, fpm, apache2 being the most common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage message reads

> -s ALL|sapi_name

`-s` selects for which server API extensions are enabled or disabled. Use it to enable an extension for the CLI, but not FPM, for instance.